# How correctly install EpiServer Commerce 7 on MVC Site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, episerver-7

I am trying to install EpiServer Commerce 7. Found this one guide  [Building EPiServer Templates with MVC Razor Part 1](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Joe-Bianco/Dates/2013/1/Building-EPiServer-Templates-with-MVC-Razor-Part-1-Page-Templates/)  Can some body explain this first step **Create a New EPiServer Project** in tutorial?  I created new project in Visual Studio  then in Development Center of EpiServer I created new site with SQL database, but it created site in another folder wwwroot. How can tie this two projects in one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the EPiServer Documentation (http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Installation-Instructions/Installing-EPiServer-updates/Installing-Commerce/):

1. Download and extract the installation files.
2. Run Setup.
3. Select the products you want to install.
4. In Extension Manager in Visual Studio, install EPiServer CMS extensions.
5. Create a site from VS using EPiServer Web Site, or from EPiServer Deployment Center.
6. In Extension Manager in VS, install NuGet Package Manager.
7. Add  "http://nuget.episerver.com/feed/packages.svc/" as EPiServer source.
8. Install EPiServer.CMS.UI for CMS, and EPiServer.Commerce for Commerce.
9. Build your project.

Answer (score 0):

Now EPIServer CMS 7.5 (8) has changed old way. You need to download Visual Studio extension. You can create empty or template projects and can do custom development on it. You can also add custom add-ons.

1- Download VS extension.
http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Installation-Instructions/installing-episerver/

Direct link
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ad95160-e72f-4355-b53e-0994d2958d3e